# how to use Velodyne VLP16 and laser_scan_matcher with cloud input?

Tags: ros, pointcloud-to-laserscan, vlp16, pointcloud, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a robot equipped with a 3D-Lidar (Velodyne VLP16) and want to use laser_scan_matcher (http://wiki.ros.org/laser_scan_matcher) to estimate it's position.
The velodyne driver (http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_pointcloud?distro=indigo) publishes *velodyne_points* (sensor_msgs/PointCloud2) which I intend to use as input for the laser_scan_matcher by setting the use_cloud_input parameter to 'true'. The following error is produced: "Invalid number of rays". After some research I found that only 10000 rays are accepted, while there are roughly ~19000 in the PointCloud2 message.

Obviously, I could always use pointcloud_to_laserscan in between to get a /scan topic out of the velodyne_points and use it as input to the laser_scan_matcher. This works fine but I was hoping to get a better result for the position estimation if I use the PointCloud2 message directly.

My question: is there a convenient way to adjust the number of published points in the PointCloud2 message? Or is there a way to circumvent the "number of rays" restriction?
I found the two following posts with similar questions/problems, if it helps:

http://answers.ros.org/question/61758/localization-just-from-imu-data/

http://answers.ros.org/question/226070/laser_datac-location/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257630/how-to-use-velodyne-vlp16-and-laser_scan_matcher-with-cloud-input?/) by [rosarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/29779/rosarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-03-22

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fiorano10](https://answers.ros.org/users/29733/fiorano10/) on 2017-10-09**:
I'm working on something similar and have the same issue. I got it working with pointcloud_to_laserscan package but I wanted to use pointcloud2 as input. Did you find a solution to the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The usual solution is the one you mention, using `pointcloud_to_laserscan`.

If you need or want more than that, you'll likely need to do some original work.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2017-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0